# Repair windows bootmanager from within windows

Tags: windows-7, mbr

How would I repair the mbr from within windows? I installed Ubuntu onto a second partition. I want to delete said partition as my need for a linux distro has now passed. Once I delete that partition grub will go broke. I know I can do this from the recovery console but I want to try from windows itself. I know in XP I could `fdisk /mbr` and in 7 I technically would use `bcdedit` but that output looks scary in my other Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the EasyBCD utility will do the trick.  It says "Windows Vista", but the bootloader is the same in Vista and Windows 7.

You can download it here:  http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1

There's an option under "Manage Bootloader" to "Reinstall the Vista Bootloader".

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the Ubuntu OS running, there might be a backup of the original MBR somewhere already.  My Slackware puts it in /boot/boot.800.  I could restore it with
     dd if=/boot/boot.800 of=/dev/sda count=1 bs=512
The /dev/sda assumes it's on the first SATA or scsi drive, if it's on second drive it'd be /dev/sdb, etc.  Old ESDI drives would be /dev/hda etc.

Comment: Thanks but I asked for a way from inside windows.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 has fdisk /fixmbr and fdisk /fixboot to fix your MBR and bootsector. It should reinstall your Windows bootloader. You must, however, perform this from a Recovery console. To use this, insert your Windows install disc, reboot and choose (R)epair during setup.

Comment: Again thanks for the idea but I was trying to do it from within windows itself.